# Batch file - how to launch non-default browser?

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser, command-line

When I run this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://target_web_site?param=arg
```

from the command line, the target page is opened in IE (as expected).

But when I attempt to do this in a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:; Check the input
IF "%1"=="" GOTO NoArg
    SET url=http://target_web_site?param=
    SET url=%url%%1
    start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" !url!
    GOTO AllDone

:NoArg
echo USAGE:
echo %0 Arg

:AllDone
```

the target page is opened in my *default* browser (Chrome). I'd like to understand why this happens and how to control which browser launches? When IE is the default browser, the target opens in IE. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, your start code works for me.  But I would try adding a pair of empty quotes to be on the safe side. `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" !url!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first set of quotes in start (which is the wrong command anyway) is the Windows Title. So you are executing a web site. There is no need for delayed expansion.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %url%
```

Comment: Thanks --- very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I read your questions, and I think you want to start a page from CMD (batch).

I'm doing this with the `start` command.

You can open a page with the command:

```
start "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776220/batch-file-how-to-launch-non-default-browser"
```

(Change the page)

Hope I helped you!